# Transfer client session from one server to another

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have a user log into a main server with a PHP application that serves numerous purposes. I want to have a completely separate application on a completely separate web server with a completely separate database, but I don't want the user to need to log in separately, but rather utilize the same authenticated session that was performed on the main server and carry it over, essentially transferring them to the other server. What is the best practice found in the industry for transferring a logged in user from one server to the other without them logging in again?

I thought of encrypting a URL that can only be encrypted/decrypted by the scripts on both servers, which share a secret encryption key.

I thought of having the source server send the destination server a secret message asking for a temporary login key that then gets attached to the URL of the destination server that the user gets sent to, and immediately invalidating the key when they get there. Should the source server talk to the destination server through an https API or through ssh?

I'm looking for some guidance for industry best practices for this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique I usually use (right or wrong) is to store a temporary hash in the database and then send a request that contains that hash to the target server along with something unique about the user, usually your auto_increment pk. The target server will check the id and hash against what's in the database and make sure there is a pending single sign on request. The target server then creates whatever session it needs and disposes of the temporary hash.

This is fairly secure as is because hijacking somebody's session in this manner would require them to guess both the id and the hash at the exact moment the single sign on is happening. Even this very tiny chance of that happening can be mitigated by storing also a state transfer date and invalidate it after 30 seconds or so.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!